# Simple Docker Filebeat Elasticsearch Composition does not Log out Docker Logs

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, kibana, filebeat

I created a docker compose for educational purposes to explore the Filebeat Logging capabilities, but I do not get Filebeat to log the logs a specific container.

I create an elastic process with certificate security, then a Kibana container on top of that. I configure the Kibana/Elastic Setup with a Filebeat container and then I would have expected the Logs in the "Discover" Tab in Kibana, but nothing is visible, no logs.

Here is my docker-compose:

```
services:
  elastic-setup:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.12.1
    user: "0"
    volumes:
      - ./elasticsearch/certs:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs
    command: >
      bash -c '
        if [ ! -f config/certs/ca.zip ]; then
          echo "Creating CA";
          bin/elasticsearch-certutil ca --silent --pem -out config/certs/ca.zip;
          unzip config/certs/ca.zip -d config/certs;
        fi;
        if [ ! -f config/certs/certs.zip ]; then
          echo "Creating certs";
          echo -ne \
          "instances:\n"\
          "  - name: search\n"\
          "    dns:\n"\
          "      - search\n"\
          "      - localhost\n"\
          "    ip:\n"\
          "      - 127.0.0.1\n"\
          > config/certs/instances.yml;
          bin/elasticsearch-certutil cert --silent --pem -out config/certs/certs.zip --in config/certs/instances.yml --ca-cert config/certs/ca/ca.crt --ca-key config/certs/ca/ca.key;
          unzip config/certs/certs.zip -d config/certs;
        fi;
        echo "Setting file permissions"
        chown -R root:root config/certs;
        find . -type d -exec chmod 750 \{\} \;;
        find . -type f -exec chmod 640 \{\} \;;
        echo "Waiting for Elasticsearch availability";
        until curl -s --cacert config/certs/ca/ca.crt https://search:9200 | grep -q "missing authentication credentials"; do sleep 30; done;
        echo "Setting kibana_system password";
        until curl -s -X POST --cacert config/certs/ca/ca.crt -u "elastic:elastic" -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://search:9200/_security/user/kibana_system/_password -d "{\"password\":\"kibana\"}" | grep -q "^{}"; do sleep 10; done;
        echo "All done!";
      '
    networks:
      - elasticnet
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "[ -f config/certs/search/search.crt ]"]
      interval: 1s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 120

  search:
    depends_on:
      elastic-setup:
        condition: service_healthy
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.12.1
    volumes:
      - ./elasticsearch/certs:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    environment:
      - node.name=search
      - cluster.name=search-cluster
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - ELASTIC_PASSWORD=elastic
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - xpack.security.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.key=certs/search/search.key
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate=certs/search/search.crt
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate_authorities=certs/ca/ca.crt
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.verification_mode=certificate
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.key=certs/search/search.key
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate=certs/search/search.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate_authorities=certs/ca/ca.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode=certificate
      - xpack.license.self_generated.type=basic
    mem_limit: 1GB
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    networks:
      - elasticnet
    healthcheck:
      test:
        [
          "CMD-SHELL",
          "curl -s --cacert config/certs/ca/ca.crt https://localhost:9200 | grep -q 'missing authentication credentials'",
        ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 120

  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:8.12.1
    volumes:
      - ./elasticsearch/certs:/usr/share/kibana/config/certs
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    environment:
      - SERVERNAME=kibana
      - ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=https://search:9200
      - ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME=kibana_system
      - ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD=kibana
      - ELASTICSEARCH_SSL_CERTIFICATEAUTHORITIES=config/certs/ca/ca.crt
    networks:
      - elasticnet
    mem_limit: 1GB
    healthcheck:
      test:
        [
          "CMD-SHELL",
          "curl -s -I http://localhost:5601 | grep -q 'HTTP/1.1 302 Found'",
        ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 30
    depends_on:
      search:
        condition: service_healthy

  filebeat-setup:
    image: docker.elastic.co/beats/filebeat:8.12.1
    command: "--strict.perms=false setup"
    user: root
    networks:
      - elasticnet
    volumes:
      - ./filebeat/filebeat.yml:/usr/share/filebeat/filebeat.yml
      - ./elasticsearch/certs:/usr/share/filebeat/config/certs
    environment:
      - ELASTICSEARCH_HOST=https://search:9200
      - KIBANA_HOST=https://kibana:5601
      - ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME=elastic
      - ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD=elastic
    depends_on:
      search:
        condition: service_healthy
      kibana:
        condition: service_healthy

  filebeat:
    image: docker.elastic.co/beats/filebeat:8.12.1
    command: "--strict.perms=false -e"
    user: root
    volumes:
      - ./filebeat/filebeat.yml:/usr/share/filebeat/filebeat.yml:ro
      - ./elasticsearch/certs:/usr/share/filebeat/config/certs
      - /var/lib/docker/containers:/var/lib/docker/containers:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
    environment:
      - ELASTICSEARCH_HOST=https://search:9200
      - KIBANA_HOST=https://kibana:5601
      - ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME=elastic
      - ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD=elastic
    networks:
      - elasticnet
    depends_on:
      filebeat-setup:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  logger:
    image: alpine:latest
    command: >
      sh -c '
        while true
        do
          echo "Log $(date)"
          sleep 1
        done
      '
    labels:
      co.elastic.logs/enabled: true
    networks:
      - elasticnet
    depends_on:
      filebeat-setup:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

networks:
  elasticnet:
    name: elasticnet
```

The Filebeat Setup (I save in a filebeat subfolder, see volumes) is pretty simple:

```
filebeat.inputs:
  - type: filestream
    id: my-filestream-id
    enabled: false
# ============================== Filebeat modules ==============================

filebeat.config.modules:
  path: ${path.config}/modules.d/*.yml
  reload.enabled: false
  #reload.period: 10s

filebeat.autodiscover:
  providers:
    - type: docker
      hints.enabled: true
      hints.default_config.enabled: false

# ======================= Elasticsearch template setting =======================

setup.template.settings:
  index.number_of_shards: 1
setup.kibana:
  host: "kibana:5601"
  username: elastic
  password: elastic
output.elasticsearch:
  # Array of hosts to connect to.
  hosts: ["search:9200"]

  # Performance preset - one of "balanced", "throughput", "scale",
  # "latency", or "custom".
  preset: balanced

  # Protocol - either `http` (default) or `https`.
  protocol: "https"

  # Authentication credentials - either API key or username/password.
  #api_key: "id:api_key"
  username: "elastic"
  password: "elastic"

  ssl.certificate_authorities: ["/usr/share/filebeat/config/certs/ca/ca.crt"]
  ssl.certificate: "/usr/share/filebeat/config/certs/search/search.crt"
  ssl.key: "/usr/share/filebeat/config/certs/search/search.key"

# ================================= Processors =================================
processors:
  - add_host_metadata:
      when.not.contains.tags: forwarded
  - add_docker_metadata: ~
```

Everything is more or less copied from the Elastic Documentation but:

1. Although I get some installed Dashboards in Kibana, during Filebeat initialiazation I get a lot of "kibana-1          | [2024-02-19T01:10:10.966+00:00][ERROR][http] 400 Bad Request" Logs and
2. As mentioned, no Logs from my Test "Logger" Container visible in the Kibana Discover Tab

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use "**container**" filebeat input **type** instead of filestream.

[Filebeat Input Container](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-input-container.html)